# How to open the “Club Penguin 3D” application in macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos-highsierra

I'm trying to open the [Club Penguin 3D](https://www.cp3d.org) application in my downloads but I can't open it

[image]

I've tried these two commands on the terminal `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine “Downloads/Club Penguin 3D/Launcher.app”` and `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Downloads/Club\ Penguin\ 3D/Launcher.app` but they don't work this is what pops up

[image]

Comment: The first version of your command fails because you have so-called smart quotes around your path rather than standard quotes you can see that the quotation marks are angled slightly. You have `“Downloads/Club Penguin 3D/Launcher.app”` instead of `"Downloads/Club Penguin 3D/Launcher.app"`. This is often cause by people using a text editor such as Word to publish their information as it automatically swaps them. For your second  error it seems that you might need to use `-dr` instead of `-d` https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104875/11520

Comment: this didn't work all I got was Davids-MBP:~ davidlopez$ xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine Downloads/Club\ Penguin\ 3D/Launcher.app
Davids-MBP:~ davidlopez$ im sorry if im slow I don't know much about Macs but I'm trying to learn